# mysql query returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php 
 $droll=$_SESSION['roll'];
 $sql=" SELECT name FROM hostel_register WHERE roll=$droll";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 echo $result;
?>
```

This code instead of returning name returns value "Resource id #5" everytime. Can someone help?

Comment: This behavior is expected and defined. The successful execution of the `mysql_query` function returns a **resultset** object, not a scalar value, not an array, etc. (N.B. **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.) [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to fetch your results

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'];
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

While fetching the records use a while loop :

```
 <?php
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['name'];
  }
 ?>
```